# Can't open the Device Manager and other Administrative tools | Blocked by Administrator (Windows 10 21H1)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, uac, blocking, device-manager

I was updating the device drivers of my computer, but it was unsuccessful, After spending so much time on the booting loop & a couple of forced shutdowns, I rolled back my system using `System Restore Point`.

But after the login when I try to launch the `Device Manager` I am getting this error.

[image: img_Device_Manager]

Not only `Device Manager`, `Component Services`, `Computer Management` & several other administrative tools also facing the same issue

I have tried to change `User Account Control Settings` but it is not doing anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your antivirus active & fully up to date?

Comment: Yes, it is active & up to date also

Comment: Run a full scan. Also see if you can install Malwarebytes & run that [it's one of the few antiviruses you can install alongside another, they won't fight.]

Comment: Are you able to add a user? And if so, can you make the new user a member of the Admin group?

Comment: The only way to disable UAC is through a Group Policy, what you can do within `User Account Control Settings` is only change the way notifications work.  Outside of the group policy UAC cannot be disabled.  There are really only two reasons you would be getting this message. The first means you are not an Administrator, and the device manager actually has been blocked, solution to that problem is to unblock it. The other  is due to the system restore something strange has happened, the simplest solution if you are not highly technical, to perform a Reset (if the system will allow you to do so)

Comment: @Ramhound I have only my account on the computer & it has admin privileges

Comment: @John no I don't it says "Something went wrong"

Comment: So at this point, since so many admin things have gone wrong, you probably need now to back up data and reinstall Windows.

Comment: An in-place repair should work.  Others that have had this exact same error message have indicate that solution worked.  Since there are dozens of questions with that exact answer I won't be submitting that particular answer myself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, one solution is worked for me that is, enabling hidden admin account

Open your Windows **PowerShell** as an **admin** & execute the following command

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

[image: img_PowerShell]

It's solved my issue, but also enabled another admin account with the name of "Administrator"

Now I have two accounts on the system, my own user account, and "Administrator" account, both are admin privileged.

As I kept both user account, I don't know what happens if I remove or try to remove the "Administrator" account

**Edit:** You can't delete it as it's the system default admin account but you can hide it using the following command

```
net user administrator /active:no
```

Comment: The `net` command has nothing to do with ***PowerShell*** so I have no idea why you emphasized it as being important.  It is located in %windir%\System32\net.exe and can do this action if it is run from anything that can launch a program with elevated privileges.

Comment: I don't know how it's working, but it's working. I execute this command from **cmd** (as admin) but it's not working there. After that, I tried **PowerShell**, it worked. 

Reference (4th Fix) https://thegeekpage.com/device-manager-is-blocked-by-administrator-in-windows-10/